# An efficient way of removing objects from an indexedDB object store that are missing a property

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am thinking about how to make a certain operation in a project of mine more efficient. The operation in its current implementation loads all objects from an object store, iterates through the array and testing whether an object is missing a property or if the property is undefined, collecting the set of such objects in a second array, and then removing all of these objects.

I am already using getAll for its obvious performance benefit over cursor iteration.

I am concurrently calling individual delete requests, so there is no speed up there but for the the indexedDB api evolving to support batch deletes on non-indexed non-keypath props that are missing values.

The issue is that I have no way of checking against the property when the property is not in the keypath of the object store without fully loading each object into memory. The objects are rather large in some cases. Sometimes one of the properties of each object is extremely large (essentially a string of an html document).

I cannot use an index, because properties not present in objects, or that do not have a value, do not appear in an index.

Is there a way to avoid loading such objects into memory?

I have thought about partitioning, and using two object stores, one for queryable props and one for full data. But then this devolves into having to do extra requests every read. My app does a lot more reading then this occasional batch delete operation.

I have thought about storing an extra property per object that always has a value like `myObject.doesOtherPropertyHaveValue` that contains 0/1 and therefore is indexable, but this doesn't seem great either. Sure I could query by just this index and use getAllKeys and that solves the problem. However, now every add/put has to maintain this functional dependency.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the records have the form `{key, prop}` where prop is the one that may not be present, you can create an index on `[key, prop]`. This will only have index records when prop is present. Then open two key-only cursors: one on the store (C1) and one on the index (C2). Check to see if the C1.primaryKey equals C2.primaryKey[0]. If so, the prop is present, advance both. If the keys are *not* equal then C1 points at a record that doesn't have the prop; delete it and advance C1. Repeat. (Watch out for edge cases when you hit the end of the range.)

Two problems with this: (1) you're still using cursors, so still paying the cost of round trips (unlike `getAll()`), and (2) if prop is large (i.e. the body of an HTML document as you mention) then even just using key cursors you're still shuffling the large amount of data around.

(In the future we'd like to tackle this by adding either a [more general query mechanism](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/45) or [custom indexing](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/33) possibly combined with [delete-on-index](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/68) - either of which would make this much easier and more efficient)

> ...collecting the set of such objects in a second array, and then removing all of these objects...

If you stick with this approach, remember that you can issue `delete()` calls as you find them; no need to collect all the objects, and you don't need to wait for the deletes to finish; you can use IDB in a "fire and forget" fashion for write operations.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I would like the delete on index stuff, because I essentially want `DELETE FROM objectStore WHERE prop not in obj or obj.prop = null or obj.prop = undefined;` where data is not even loaded into js. The one issue I have with the fire and forget aspect is that I very much prefer the syntax `await Promise.all(deleteRequestPromises);` over `Promise.all(deletes).catch()`. Of course, I wouldn't need this if I had delete on index, but I just wanted to add that point regarding the way it currently works.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path that denormalization may be necessary to improve performance. From the indexedDB docs, there's no way to query the way you need to unfortunately.

If the true bottleneck is I/O or marshalling data into JS-land, then maybe try compressing the data before writing and uncompressing when you actually need to do something with it? GZIP can compress text very well, sometimes up to 70% less. There are a few GZIP libraries for JS that could work:

https://github.com/nodeca/pako

But, as always, benchmark!